# Set @Repository to work with specific DataSource Spring-boot

Tags: java, database, jpa, spring-boot, datasource

I have 2 DataSources defined in my Spring-boot Project and I also have 2 @Repository.

I have this code in my

> Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.opes.kyc_adapter.repository.postgresql", "com.opes.kyc_adapter.repository.mysql"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.opes.kyc_adapter.model.postgresql", "com.opes.kyc_adapter.model.mysql"})
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private MessageRepositoryMySQL repositoryMySQL;

    @Autowired
    private MessageRepositoryPostgreSQL repositoryPostgreSQL;


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            repositoryMySQL.save(new MessageOriginal("My post number #" + (i+1)));
            repositoryPostgreSQL.save(new MessageExtracted("My post number #" + (i+1), "User #" + (i+1)));

        }

    }

}
```

As you can see I have 2 @Repository

What happens is that each repo is supposed to add data to a different DataSource, but both are adding to the MySQL Datasouce.

Here follows the rest of the code:

> DataBaseConfigurationMySQL.java

```
@Configuration
public class DataBaseConfigurationMySQL implements EnvironmentAware {

    private RelaxedPropertyResolver jpaPropertyResolver;

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private PersistenceUnitManager persistenceUnitManager;

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.jpaPropertyResolver = new RelaxedPropertyResolver(environment, "spring.jpa.");
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("jdbcTemplate")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        if (persistenceUnitManager != null) {
            entityManagerFactoryBean
                    .setPersistenceUnitManager(persistenceUnitManager);
        }
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.opes.kyc_adapter.model.mysql");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap().putAll(jpaPropertyResolver.getSubProperties("properties."));
        Map<String, Object> properties = entityManagerFactoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap();
        properties.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", jpaPropertyResolver.getProperty("hibernate.naming-strategy", SpringNamingStrategy.class.getName()));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", jpaPropertyResolver.getProperty("hibernate.ddl-auto", "create-drop"));
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .url("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kyc-adapter-mysql")
                .driverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
                .username("root")
                .password("pass")
                .build();
    }   




}
```

> DataBaseConigurationPostgreSQL.java

```
@Configuration
public class DataBaseConfigurationPostgreSQL implements EnvironmentAware {

    private RelaxedPropertyResolver jpaPropertyResolver;

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private PersistenceUnitManager persistenceUnitManager;

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.jpaPropertyResolver = new RelaxedPropertyResolver(environment, "spring.jpa.");
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("jdbcTemplate")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        if (persistenceUnitManager != null) {
            entityManagerFactoryBean
                    .setPersistenceUnitManager(persistenceUnitManager);
        }
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.opes.kyc_adapter.model.postgresql");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap().putAll(jpaPropertyResolver.getSubProperties("properties."));
        Map<String, Object> properties = entityManagerFactoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap();
        properties.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", jpaPropertyResolver.getProperty("hibernate.naming-strategy", SpringNamingStrategy.class.getName()));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", jpaPropertyResolver.getProperty("hibernate.ddl-auto", "create-drop"));
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .url("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/kyc-adapter-postgresql")
                .driverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver")
                .username("postgres")
                .password("pass")
                .build();
    }
```

> MessageOriginal.java

```
@Entity
public class MessageOriginal {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String message;

    public MessageOriginal(){

    }

    public MessageOriginal(String message){
        this.message = message;     
    }

    //getters and setters
}
```

> MessageExtracted.java

```
@Entity
public class MessageExtracted {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String message;

    private String userName;

    public MessageExtracted(){

    }

    public MessageExtracted(String message, String userName){
        this.message = message;
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    //getters and setters
}
```

> MessageRepositoryMySQL.java

```
@Repository
public interface MessageRepositoryMySQL extends CrudRepository<MessageOriginal, Long>{

}
```

> MessageRepositoryPostgreSQL.java

```
@Repository
public interface MessageRepositoryPostgreSQL extends CrudRepository<MessageExtracted, Long>{

}
```

Comment: Although it's very long post to read but what is your question?

Comment: Split the `@EnableJpaRepositories` into 2 separate ones, tell it which `EntityManagerFactory` to use and only give it the specific package it needs to scan. Your current setup will never work as one entity manager config overrides the other (the method name is the name of the bean).